# How to add programmatically ng-options into select tag in onsen ui?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

How to add programmatically ng-options into select tag in onsen ui with angularJS?

Thank you and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use list of model which has an id and a name.
For example,

```
<select ng-model="model_selected.id" ng-options="model.id as model.name for model in list"></select>
```

Adding:
 A detailed example is following. Html is

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select ng-model="model_selected.id" ng-options="model.id as model.name for model in list"></select>
<div ng-click="change()">Change</div>
</div>
```

and js is

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {  
  $scope.list = [ { "id" : "1" , "name" : "Dog" } , { "id" : "2" , "name" : "Cat" } , { "id" : "3" , "name" : "Bunny"} ];
    $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.list = [ { "id" : "1" , "name" : "Wolf" } , { "id" : "2" , "name" : "Lion" } , { "id" : "3" , "name" : "Hare" } ];
  }
});
```

Initially, you can choose one from dog, cat and bunney.
After click the change anchor, you can choose one from wolf, lion and hare.

Comment: Are more Explain? Thank you